# How to call a toString from a superclass

Tags: java, tostring

I have to make program that asks for the users name, address, phone number, customer number, and whether or not the customer would like to be added to the mailing list (displayed as true or false) and then display the user information I've got the entire program working perfectly the only issue is that there is a blank space inbetween both my toString() methods. The assignment requires me to make the entire program in one file without a blank space here is an example output:

Example

```html
Customer:
Name: Julia Stevens
Address: 77 Massachusetts Ave Cambridge, MA 02139
Phone·Number: 617-777-7777
Customer·Number: 928734502
Recieve·Mail?: false
```

Here is my code:
Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   String personInput;
   String customerInput;
   Person A = new Person("", "", "");
   Customer B = new Customer("", false, "", "", "");

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter name of customer:");
    personInput = input.nextLine();
    A.setName(personInput);
    System.out.print("Enter address of customer:");
    personInput = input.nextLine();
    A.setAddress(personInput);
    System.out.print("Enter phone number of customer:");
    personInput = input.nextLine();
    A.settNumber(personInput);
    System.out.print("Enter customer number:");
    customerInput = input.nextLine();
    B.setcNumber(customerInput);
    System.out.print("Enter yes/no -- does the customer want to receive mail?:");
    customerInput = input.nextLine();
    B.setmList(false);

    if (customerInput.equals("yes"))
        B.setmList(true);
    else if (customerInput.equals("no"))
        B.setmList(false);

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Cutomer: ");
    System.out.println(A.toString());
    System.out.println(B.toString());

}

private static class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String tNumber;

    public Person(String name, String address, String tNumber) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.tNumber = tNumber;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() 
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) 
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String gettNumber() 
    {
        return tNumber;
    }

    public void settNumber(String tNumber) 
    {
        this.tNumber = tNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + "\n"
             + "Address: " + address + "\n"
             + "Phone Number: " + tNumber + "\n";
    }
}
    private static class Customer extends Person
    {
        private String cNumber;
        private boolean mList;

        public Customer(String cNumber, boolean mList, String name, String address, String tNumber) 
        {
            super(name, address, tNumber);
            this.cNumber = cNumber;
            this.mList = mList;
        }

        public String getcNumber() 
        {
            return cNumber;
        }

        public void setcNumber(String cNumber) 
        {
            this.cNumber = cNumber;
        }

        public boolean ismList() 
        {
            return mList;
        }

        public void setmList(boolean mList) 
        {
            this.mList = mList;
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer Number: " + cNumber + "\n"
             + "Receive Mail?: " + mList;
    }
```

Comment: `return super.toString() + "Customer Number: " + cNumber + "\n"
             + "Receive Mail?: " + mList;`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that didn't work the space is gone now but the name, phone number, and address isn't displaying now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eeeemmm Just make it System.out.print - not System.out.println
on these lines

```
System.out.println("Cutomer: ");
System.out.print(A.toString());
System.out.print(B.toString());}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the **super** keyword to call the parent class.

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\n Customer Number: " + cNumber + "\n"
             + "Receive Mail?: " + mList;
    }
```

You can access all properties and methods with the keyword super just need the correct access specifiers!

Comment: i tried that but it's not displaying the name, address, and phone number after using super.toString()

Comment: the thing is the keyword **static**

Comment: well the problem is that the assignment requires that it all be in the same file so i can't do that if it's because of the keyword static i'll have to find another work around.